# How to relate traffic to a Banner even thought they didn`t click on it and just searched the site afterwords

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, bug-tracking, banner, web-analytics

I will like to know if there is a way to relate a user to a publicity banner on a  3rd party site that came to my site not directly by clicking on it, but they search for my site afterwords. FYI - I use Google analytic to track my traffic.

An example flow is as described bellow:

1. The user saw the banner on a site that I promote trough. (The user don`t click on the banner)
2. The user sometime after remembers that he saw the banner and search for my site on Google/Bing.
3. The user becomes a client in my site.
4. Here is the problem, I thought that the user came from an add-words search instead the real reason that was the banner in the other site.

Hope you can help me resolve this issue.
Thanks!

FYI - I use Google analytic to track my traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, you won't be able to track these kinds of visitors with just Google Analytics. If the site you're advertising on uses an ad server like DoubleClick, they've developed technology for just this use case (though you'll need to place the DC javascript tracking on your site in order for it to work correctly).

Comment: Thanks Tom, just to be sure, you are talking about DoubleClick by Google? http://www.google.com/doubleclick/

Comment: Yep, that's correct - though it's also possible the site you're advertising on uses a different ad server (which almost certainly has similar functionality).